# How can I change the colour matching option in the Default Settings printer preset?

Tags: catalina, printing, settings, preferences

Specifically, I want to change the colour matching for my Canon Pixma G3500 from Canon Color Matching to ColorSync.

When editing using the GUI, the Default Settings, and Draft Printing on Plain Paper and Fine Printing on Plain Paper can't be saved over or deleted.

I know how to create custom settings but ideally I would like to change the defaults to avoid accidental wasted prints in future, because the custom settings appear lower down the drop-down menu so could be missed if printing in haste or when tired.

I searched plist files in /Library/Preferences/ and ~/Library/Preferences/ but drew a blank.

Comment: Good start to this by listing a specific printer. What happens when you use the GUI to set a preference for one specific item?

Comment: I can't save the settings with the same file name. I also can't go to Show presets and delete Default Settings, Draft Printing on Plain Paper and Fine Printing on Plain Paper. My workaround is to make custom settings beginning with the word 'Proper', but its far from ideal.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the `Default Settings` print preset, but if you make a new Preset, and print with it, then MacOS normally offers the same preset again, the next time you print.

In earlier versions of MacOS, if you held down <kbd>Option</kbd> when you pressed OK in the Print menu, the settings would be saved as the default, but that doesn't seem necessary now. You could try it if it isn't working.

You can change the defaults of the printer by accessing the CUPS web interface, but that doesn't always include ColorSync options.

The first time you try this, you need to enable the CUPS web interface. In Terminal, type `cupsctl WebInterface=yes`

In a web browser, go to http://localhost:631

Then you'll see the CUPS controls. Click on "Printers" in the bar along the top. Choose your printer from the List. and in the drop down list, select **Set Default Options**.

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks. Can you possibly explain how you are certain that the Default Settings preset can't be changed, so I can accept the answer? I think my best option, along with my current workaround, is to feed back to Apple that their default settings are wrong for this printer (and presumably most/all Canon printers).

Comment: You can change the defaults, but not the print preset. If you try to save a Print Preset with the name "Default Settings", the OK button greys out. Defaults are always wrong for somebody: that's why you can change them. Canon makes the drivers, not Apple. Presumably they value their own color management over Apple's

Comment: Yes, except you can't change these particular defaults, or rather the Colour Matching option of them, only create custom settings as options below them. I'm going to wait a while and see if anyone posts a hacky way to change the default colour matching.

Comment: Thanks for the point about Canon being responsible.I established through a discussion with Canon support that their colour matching conflicts with Apple's built in colour matching, hence ColorSync is the correct option, at least for the several applications I tested with. So I'll contact Canon to ask them to change the default.

Comment: You'll be waiting a long time. Just set your Print Preset as you want it, and use that.  Also, have you checked the CUPS interface?

Comment: Yes, I did check it, and as you predicted there was no option for colour matching. I've contacted Canon to let them know of the issue.